Сделать прилипающее меню к тулбару
У меня есть сайт, с шапкой в самом верху. Шапка прокручивается, под ней есть тулбар, который прилипает к верху окна. Так и должно быть. В тулбаре есть кнопка, которая выдвигает менюшку сбоку. Менюшка находится под тулбаром и должна прилипать к тулбару.
Несложными манипуляциями поставил margin-top, равный высоте тулбара, и слава тебе господи. Но это при прокрутке. А вот если пролистать страницу в самый верх, то получится, что менюшка наезжает на шапку, потом тулбар, потом оставшаяся часть меню. А мне надо, чтобы именно меню было сцеплено с тулбаром, да притом еще и прокручивалось, ибо длина превосходит размеры экрана.


@font-face {
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('https://kristy98755.github.io/startpage/CenturyGothic.woff')format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('https://kristy98755.github.io/startpage/CenturyGothic-Bold.woff')format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  src: url('https://kristy98755.github.io/startpage/CenturyGothic-BoldItalic.woff')format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
  src: url('https://kristy98755.github.io/startpage/CenturyGothic-Italic.woff')format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Palatino Linotype';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('https://kristy98755.github.io/startpage/PalatinoLinotype.woff')format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Palatino Linotype';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('https://kristy98755.github.io/startpage/PalatinoLinotypeBold.woff')format('woff');
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
}

iframe {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 90vh;
}

.zagolovok {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('https://kristy98755.github.io/startpage/repeatable.png');
  height: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  font-family: 'Palatino Linotype';
  font-size: calc(2vw + 2vh + 5vmax);
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-shadow: -2px -2px 0 #DDD, 2px -2px 0 #DDD, -2px 2px 0 #DDD, 2px 2px 0 #DDD;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Стили для тулбара */

.toolbar {
  position: sticky;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* Добавлено для размещения элементов */
  align-items: center;
  /* Центрирование по вертикали */
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #a7a71d;
  padding: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: calc(3vw + 2vh + 1.2vmin);
}

.burger {
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
  /* Отступ от левого края */
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}

.burger::before,
.burger::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.burger::before {
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 22px 0 #000;
  transition: box-shadow .3s .15s, top .3s .15s, transform .3s;
}

.burger::after {
  bottom: 0;
  transition: bottom .3s .15s, transform .3s;
}

.burger.active::before {
  top: 22px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: box-shadow .15s, top .3s, transform .3s .15s;
}

.burger.active::after {
  bottom: 22px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition: bottom .3s, transform .3s .15s;
}

.hidden-items {
  position: sticky;
  /* Меню прилипает к верху окна при прокрутке */
  top: 0;
  margin-top: calc(3vw + 2vh + 1.2vmin + 22px);
  /* Меню будет размещаться под тулбаром */
  max-height: calc(100vh - (3vw + 2vh + 1.2vmin + 22px));
  /* Ограничение по высоте до высоты окна */
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Вертикальная прокрутка при переполнении */
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  /* Перемещаем элемент за пределы экрана */
  transition: transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
  /* Переходы для перемещения и прозрачности */
  width: 100%;
  font-size: calc(2vw + 2vh + 1vmin);
  background: #d0d048;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 8;
  /* Чтобы элемент находился поверх других элементов */
}

.hidden-items.active {
  transform: translateX(0);
  /* Перемещаем элемент в видимую область */
}

.plitka {
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: calc(2vw + 2vh + 1vmin);
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.plitka-very-first {
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: calc(2vw + 2vh + 1vmin);
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.catalog {
  /* Это просто триггер для нажатия */
}

.arrow {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto 20px;
  width: 66px;
  height: 30px;
}

.arrow-left {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 10px;
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(35deg);
  float: right;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.arrow-left:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: black;
  width: 40px;
  height: 10px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 6px 10px 10px 6px;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 1.7, 0.35, 0.8);
  z-index: -1;
}

.arrow-right {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 10px;
  left: 26px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 10px;
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-35deg);
  float: right;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.arrow-right:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: black;
  width: 40px;
  height: 10px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 10px 6px 6px 10px;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 1.7, 0.35, 0.8);
  z-index: -1;
}

.open .arrow-left:after {
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: rotate(-70deg);
}

.open .arrow-right:after {
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: rotate(70deg);
}

.submenu1 {
  display: flex;
  transition: 0.5s ease-out;
  max-height: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #a7a71d;
  z-index: 12;
  border-bottom: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.submenu1.visible {
  display: flex;
  transition: 0.5s ease-out;
  max-height: calc((2vw + 2vh + 1vmin + 40px + 3px) * 30);
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #a7a71d;
  z-index: 12;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.greencard {
  width: 85vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 3px ridge #AAA;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
}

.greencard img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.greencard .info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 15%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: #fff;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: calc(1vw + 1.5vh + 1vmin);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.image-container:hover .info {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.greencard .caption {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #d0d048;
  font-size: calc(1vw + 1vh + 1vmin);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.greencard:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.cards-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.margins {
  margin: 10px;
}
<div class="toolbar" align="center">
  <button class="burger"></button>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
      const hiddenItems = document.querySelector('.hidden-items');

      burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        burger.classList.toggle('active');
        if (hiddenItems) { // Проверка на наличие элемента
          hiddenItems.classList.toggle('active');
        } else {
          console.warn('Элемент с классом .hidden-items не найден');
        }

      });
    });
  </script>


  <font style="display:block; position=absolute; margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
    ДВЕРИ</font>
  <font style="width:70px;height:50px;"> </font>
</div>
<div class="hidden-items">
  <div class="plitka"><a href="https://kristy98755.github.io/m.startpage">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></div>
  <div class="plitka"><a href="#">ПОИСК</a></div>
  <div class="plitka catalog active">

    КАТАЛОГ

    <div class="arrow">
      <span class="arrow-left"></span>
      <span class="arrow-right"></span>
    </div>



    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        document.querySelectorAll(".catalog").forEach(function(element) {
          element.addEventListener("click", function() {
            // Тогглируем класс "open" на стрелке
            const arrow = this.querySelector(".arrow");
            if (arrow) {
              arrow.classList.toggle("open");
            }

            // Тогглируем видимость подменю
            const subMenu = this.nextElementSibling; // Подразумевается, что .submenu1 идет сразу после .catalog
            if (subMenu) {
              subMenu.classList.toggle("visible");
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>

  </div>
  <div class="submenu1">
    <div class="plitka active"><a href="kristy98755.github.io/m.doors/index.html">Двери</a></div>
    <div class="plitka"><a href="frames.html">Рамы</a></div>
    <div class="plitka"><a href="staircase.html">Лестницы</a></div>
    <div class="plitka"><a href="tables.html">Столы</a></div>
    <div class="plitka"><a href="lavochki.html">Лавки</a></div>
    <div class="plitka"><a href="chairs.html">Стулья</a></div>
    <div class="plitka catalog">Погонаж

      <div class="arrow">
        <span class="arrow-left"></span>
        <span class="arrow-right"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="submenu1" style="background-color: #777700">
      <div class="plitka" style="border-top:1px solid black;"><a href="blockhouse.html">Блок-хаус</a></div>
      <div class="plitka"><a href="lining.html">Вагонка</a></div>
      <div class="plitka"><a href="floorboard.html">Половая доска</a></div>
      <div class="plitka"><a href="baseboard.html">Плинтус</a></div>
      <div class="plitka"><a href="doorjamb.html">Наличник</a></div>
      <div class="plitka"><a href="imitation-timber.html">Имитация бруса</a></div>
      <div class="plitka"><a href="planken.html">Планкен</a></div>
      <div class="plitka"><a href="shields-40-mm.html">Щиты 40 мм</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="plitka catalog">Для бань и саун
      <div class="arrow">
        <span class="arrow-left"></span>
        <span class="arrow-right"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="submenu1" style="background-color: #777700">
      <div class="plitka" style="border-top:1px solid black;"><a href="ladles.html">Ковши</a></div>
      <div class="plitka"><a href="traps.html">Трапы</a></div>
      <div class="plitka"><a href="lamps.html">Светильники</a></div>
      <div class="plitka"><a href="deckchairs.html">Шезлонги</a></div>
      <div class="plitka"><a href="salt.html">Гималайская соль<a></div>
                <div class="plitka"><a href="headrests.html">Подголовники</a></div>
      <div class="plitka"><a href="mugs.html">Кружки</a></div>
      <div class="plitka"><a href="dousing-buckets.html">Вёдра-обливайки</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="plitka"><a href="address.html">АДРЕС</a></div>
  <div class="plitka"><a href="contacts.html">КОНТАКТЫ</a></div>

</div>



Превью есть на kristy98755.github.io/m.doors , смотреть только в мобильной версии, на пк код другой (переадресация)

Зачем вам margin-top и position: fixed? Для размещения элемента с position: sticky, когда его родителя начинают прокручивать, есть свойство top:
.hidden-items {
  position: sticky;
  /* Меню прилипает к верху окна при прокрутке */
  top: calc(3vw + 2vh + 1.2vmin + 22px);
  /* Весь остальной код без изменений, но без position: fixed и margin-top */
}

